# How do I pass an edited Flex datagrid to a CFC to insert to a database

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, coldfusion, cfc

I have a datagrid which is editable and I need to send that back to the database via a CFC for insertion into the database after all the editing is complete. Dumping the array collection to cfdump tells me that I have an array with items and a structure but i cannot understand how to "loop" through each and insert into the DB.

There seems to be very little written which actually works! My MXML and CFC are below but give me the error of "You have attempted to dereference a scalar variable of type class coldfusion.runtime.Array as a structure with members."  -which is nice

all help is much appreciated - thanks

```
[Bindable]
private var getconsent:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
{LocationName:'Service A', Contact: 'Bob Jones' },  
{LocationName:'Service B', Contact: 'Jane Smith' },
{LocationName:'Service c', Contact: 'Doug Johnson' },   
{LocationName:'Service d', Contact: 'John Jackson'}   
]);  

public function send():void {  
cfdata.sendData(getconsent.source);  
}  

public function send_Result(event:ResultEvent):void {  
Alert.show('ok'); 
}  

public function send_Fault(event:FaultEvent):void {  
Alert.show(event.fault.message);  
} 

]]>  
</mx:Script>  

<mx:RemoteObject 
id="cfdata" 
showBusyCursor="true" 
destination="ColdFusion"  
source="buildtest.test2">  

<mx:method name="sendData" result="send_Result(event)" fault="send_Fault(event)" />  
</mx:RemoteObject>  

<mx:DataGrid id="myGrid" 
dataProvider="{getconsent}" editable="true" > 
<mx:columns>
<mx:DataGridColumn dataField="LocationName" width="150"
editable="false"/>

<mx:DataGridColumn dataField="Contact" width="150" /> 

</mx:columns> 
</mx:DataGrid> 
<mx:Button label="Update DB" click="send()"/>
```

```
<cfcomponent displayname="sendData" output="false" >  
    <cffunction name="sendData" access="remote"  output="no" returnType="void"          required="yes" >  

        <cfargument name="getconsent" type="any" required="true">  

        <cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(getconsent.dataprovider)#" index="i">  

            <cfquery name="clientconsent" datasource="gvr">  

                INSERT INTO ClientConsent"
                        (Location)
                VALUES
                ('#getconsent.dataprovider.LocationName[i]#')

            </cfquery>
        </cfloop>
    </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

array
    1 struct
     Contact Bob    Jones
     LocationName   Service A
     mx_internal_uid    807D204F-A315-7D78-C745-BAD78087CB28

```
 2 struct 
 Contact        Jane Smith  
 LocationName   Service B  
 mx_internal_uid    EAA43EF4-A7EA-82C9-5F3C-BAD780D7FD6F  

 3 struct 
 Contact        Doug Johnson  
 LocationName   Service c  
 mx_internal_uid    9768D6D2-8F97-5F4D-767C-BAD780D7B478
```

Comment: pls use cfloop INSIDE cfquery, not the other way around, for performance reason. :)

Comment: To expand on Henry's comment, currently you're creating a new connection to the database for each query. If you put the loop inside, there's just one connection created. This assumes the datasource driver you're using allows you to post multiple commands (separated with a semi-colon), which not all of them do.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using CF9, try DCD with Flex 4:
http://ria.dzone.com/articles/flash-remoting-and-coldfusion

If you're using CF8 with Flex 3, try LCDS:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/data_app.html

Comment: Thanks for the point on putting the cfloop inside the query i will do that (school boy error i guess ;)

However i am not using LCDS just a straight connection from flex 3 to cf7 to SQLExpress DB- this should be easy but I just seem to be be missing something obvious.

Comment: I have added the cfdump to the original question - the bit that puzzles me is that it is an array, with a structure, with members and this is what coldfusion is complaining about - but thats what an array is????

Comment: So you're getting an array of struct, try #getconsent.dataprovider[i].LocationName# ?

Answer (score 0):

Would it be easier for you to work with a query object instead of an array of structs? I created a UDF to convert an ArrayCollection to a Query [[ArrayCollectionToQuery](http://fusiongrokker.com/post/udf-arraycollectiontoquery)] in CF after it's returned from your Flex application.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Adam thanks for this it looks very useful, however i am not sure how to use it to insert data into my DB

```
<cfquery name="clientconsent" datasource="gvr">
INSERT INTO dbo.ClientConsent
(Location, ClientAppointments, ClientDemographics)
VALUES(
      #qresult#
)
</cfquery>
```